# $\lim(x^2+y^2)/(x-y)$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove (without polar coordinates) that the $\lim \frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$ when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ does not exist?
Moreover, can I use $(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)(x-y)$ in this case? 
If I do it seems strange because I would get $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}=x+y$ and the limit would be zero. Whereas if I try finding the limit along $y=mx$, the function becomes $\frac{x(1+m^2)}{1-m}$ which suggest that if m approaches 1 the function goes to $\pm \infty$.

If I try polar coordinates I get $\frac{r}{\sin{a}-\cos{a}}$ which suggests that the limit does not exist (and if a approaches $\pi/4$ the expression is $\pm \infty$.
Than you!

Comment: Watch out: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$, but $x^2+y^2 \ne (x+y)(x-y)$...

Comment: Compare $f(2y,y)$ and $f(y+y^2,y)$ when $y\to0$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake, StackTD, thank you Did and Git Gud for the answer!